# Differences between "hatred" and "hate"

Tags: difference, word-choice

As I understand them, when used as nouns they both mean the same: a strong feeling of dislike, but I'm not sure about how "intense" are each one related to the other.

Does one of them represent a stronger feeling than the other, or their difference resides more in the context where they are used?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Hate* and *hatred*, when used as nouns, have the same meaning. The difference between them is that *hate* is also used as modifier (e.g. *a hate campaign*), while *hatred* is not used as modifier (as it would be in *a hatred campaign*).

Comment: By *modifier*, do you mean adjective?

Comment: I mean a noun that is used as attribute of another noun. A modifier precedes the noun that modifies, and it can be an adjective, such as in _good family house_. (Both _good_ and _family_ are modifiers of _house_).

Comment: hate can be used as a noun? So I could say `my hate`?

Comment: @JonathandeM. _Hate_ is a verb, and a noun. In _feelings of hate and revenge_, _hate_ is a noun. I am not sure about saying _my hate_, but I guess it is like saying _my dislike_. If one is acceptable, then also the other one should be acceptable. Probably it should be _my hating_, and _my disliking_.

Comment: *hatred campaign* is perfectly grammatical. There are no nouns that cannot be clumped with other nouns to make a noun phrase.

Comment: @JonathandeM. Yes. For example, "My hate for him began when he shot my dog." I think almost anyplace where you say "hatred" you could say "hate", without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 17):

*Hate* is the verb, *hatred* the noun.  *Hate* is also used as a noun, but *hatred* is not a verb.

From an intensity viewpoint, and when used in a noun context, there is no difference i.e. hate = hatred.

*The hate he felt for her matched the hatred she felt for him*.  You could switch the two words around in that sentence with no difference to the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

rule of thumb for English: no two different words have the same meaning.

I use 'hate' as a noun only when modifying another noun, e.g.: hate speech or hate crime.

While people are using 'hate' as a standalone noun more today than before, possibly thanks to the incessant use of it as a standalone noun by groups such as ADL, 'hatred' is always valid as the standalone noun where 'hate' could be.

So for sake of clarity I suggest using 'hatred' unless you are modifying another noun.