# She has hating AGAINST / FOR her?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition goes together with "hating" (as a noun)  in the following contexts?

> Ann took Lee's boyfriend,  therfore Lee has hating **against / for** Ann.
>
> They have hating **against / for**  atheism / religions.

Comment: They hate the *direct object*.

Comment: An active verb: "Lee hates Ann."

Comment: I know that it's possible to use the direct way (=They hate someone),  but the question is on the other way. I'd like to know how to use the word **"hating"** as a noun.

Comment: The noun form of the verb is [hatred](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hatred).

Comment: Then, my assuming was a mistake. I don't really know why I assumed that hating is the noun form of theverb hate. I learnt something new today. Please write it as an answer. Also the word "hate" by itself may be a noun.  https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hate_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun form of the verb is not **hating** but **hatred**. In the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hatred):

> NOUN
>
> Intense dislike; hate.
>
> *racial hatred*
>   *his murderous hatred of his brother*

Or **hate** also in the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hate):

> NOUN
>
> Intense dislike.
>   *feelings of hate and revenge*

What is the difference? Please see this [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/428/differences-between-hatred-and-hate).